# FlashCards for Android and Web

Tags: android, web-apps, flashcard

I search a FlashCard application and online service.

Required Features:

- learning cards with android app, even if offline
- adding cards with android app, even if offline
- web page where I can learn with browser
- exporting the cards I created.

Things I already tried:

- Anki: AFAIK there is no web page where I can learn with browser.
- OrangeOrApple Flashcards: http://orangeorapple.com/Flashcards/
- studyblue: AFAIK you can't add new cards if you offline (android app)

Comment: Anki does have a web app: [Anki web](https://ankiweb.net/about)

Comment: @Tymric is it possible to learn with Anki via web? Up to now I thought the web interface is very limited and you are not able to learn via web.

Comment: According to their *about* page, reviewing is possible, but it's limited to text-only cards. Quote: "AnkiWeb can be used to **review online** when you don't have access to your home computer, [...] **While it is possible to create basic text-only cards and review them using only AnkiWeb**, to download shared decks, take advantage of multimedia features and so on, you will need to use the free computer version as well."

Comment: @Tymric I tried Anki several months ago on an ubuntu PC. It was way too complicated. Too many features, not easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

I tried some other flash card applications, and now I use Anki again.

I use the web and the android version.

Installing the desktop version fails on Ubuntu 17.04. But web and android is enough for me.